# printf and reading text file

Tags: java, printf

I'm having problems getting my code to sum up all of the salaries of a text file. It's supposed to sum all of them, as well as give me an average salary. Also I'm having troubles getting one of the lines in the output to format correctly. Please help, I'm still very new to programmimg! Here is my main.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class fileIn
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String fName;
        String lName;
        String rank;
        double salary = 0;
        double newSal = 0;
        Scanner inFile = null;
        Employee[] emp = new Employee[20];
        int numEmployee = 0;

        // open the file
        try
        {
            inFile = new Scanner(new File("employee.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: File employee.txt not found ");
        }

        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {

            fName = inFile.next();
            lName = inFile.next();
            rank = inFile.next();
            newSal = inFile.nextDouble();
            salary += newSal;
            emp[numEmployee] = new Employee(fName, lName, rank, salary);
            numEmployee++;

        }

        System.out.println("Acme Corporation \n");
        System.out.printf("Number Of Employees: %5d ", numEmployee);
        System.out.printf("\nAverage Salary: %13.2f", salary / numEmployee);
        System.out.printf("\nAnnual Total %16.2f", salary );

        System.out.printf("\n\n%-8s %15s %10s", "Name", "Rank", "Salary\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < numEmployee; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s, %s \t%7s %11.2f\n", emp[i].getlName(),
                    emp[i].getfName(), emp[i].getRank(), emp[i].getSalary());

        }
        inFile.close();
    }

}
```

and here is a sample output:

```
Acme Corporation 

Number Of Employees:     9 
Average Salary:      58740.50
Annual Total         528664.54

Name                Rank    Salary
------------------  ----  ---------
Jones, William       B2    42500.00
Baker, Susan         A3   107500.00
Caine, Horatio       A1   191268.95
Baer, Teddy          B4   244268.95
Gator, Allie         A2   292268.95
Mander, Sally        A1   354392.84
Aspargus, Amy        A1   454442.84
Huckleberry, Henry           B1   495677.34
Rutabaga, Ryan       B2   528664.54
```

The average salary and annual total are completely wrong, the total should be over 2 million and the average salary is supposed to be approximately 300k.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: how does the file you read look? the scanners `next()` reads whole lines, what might not be what you want

Comment: The text file looks just like the output, just not formatted. There are just spaces between the names, rank and salary.

Comment: Then the whole file is 1 line and the data is just separated with spaces? Then you'd need to read the whole file in a string and access the parts by splitting it to an array at the spaces: `String[] parts = string.split(" ");`

Comment: Can you post the input file as well or a sample of it?

Comment: No, the file is written with one name, one rank and one salary per line

Comment: William Jones B2 42500  
Susan Baker A3 65000  
Horatio Caine A1 83768.95  
Teddy Baer B4 53000  
Allie Gator A2 48000  
Sally Mander A1 62123.89  
Amy Aspargus A1 100050  
Henry Huckleberry B1 41234.5  
Ryan Rutabaga B2 32987.2

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to this site as well and I don't know how to put them all on a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning the cummulative salary to every new employee-input:

```
emp[numEmployee] = new Employee(fName, lName, rank, salary);
```

Shouldn't this be?

```
emp[numEmployee] = new Employee(fName, lName, rank, newSal);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Any thoughts on how to fix the formatting for Henry Huckleberry?

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you can keep track of the longest name in your while-loop and adjust the format to that one? Something like `int max_length; int length = fName().length() + lName().length(); if (length > max_length) max_length = length;`? Or if you're sure the names won't exceed a certain amount of characters you could make the fixed width a little bigger. This topic might be interesting: [formatting-perfectly-with-printf-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421674/formatting-perfectly-with-printf-in-java).