# Java - Formatting multiple array output

Tags: java, arrays, formatting

I'm new to java. I am trying to figure out how to format multiple arrays that are being filled in while the program is running (thanks to user input).

When I print the arrays, they do not format. I would use " " spaces, but the output of the arrays are dependent on what the user inputs. What I have is:

```
System.out.println("Order Summary:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Type                   Size          Quantity    Price");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        for (i = 0; i < boolCount; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(typeArray[i] + sizeArray[i] + quantityArray[i] + priceArray[i]); //How to format?
        }
```

which would print out whatever is in the arrays without spaces. typeArray, sizeArray, and priceArray are String arrays, while quantityArray is an integer array.

I probably need to do System.out.printf(Enter code here) but I'm not sure how to do that with arrays. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is what I get if I add "\t" between the arrays:

```
System.out.println(typeArray[i] + "\t\t" + sizeArray[i] + "\t" + quantityArray[i] + "\t" + priceArray[i]);

Order Summary:
Type                   Size          Quantity    Price
---------------------------------------------------------
BBQ Chicken     Large   2   $25.98
Chicken-Bacon Ranch     Personal    22  $175.78
Meat Lovers     Extra Large 33  $791.67

Order total: $993.43

---------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT: This is what I get with:

```
System.out.printf("%-23.23s %-14.14s %-12.12d %-5.5s", typeArray[i], sizeArray[i], quantityArray[i], priceArray[i]);

Order Summary:

Type                   Size          Quantity    Price
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 12
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Formatter.java:2984)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2729)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at pizzamenu.PizzaMenu.main(PizzaMenu.java:372)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Could you try appending tab characters "\t" between the values ?

Comment: Actually didn't think of that, give me a second to try

Comment: How about defining a maximum field length n, write a method that pads up to n or truncates down to n, then concatenate those length modified tokens with spaces?

Comment: What I am trying to do is an order summary after user orders pizza. Some of the 'specialty pizzas' have long names/short names which messes up the "\t" between the code, will edit answer to show

Comment: I think this would be the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14421916/2961429

Comment: Actually yeah, that would work, thanks for the link. How would it work with arrays? He's passing integers in the answer to that link you sent me, I would need to pass array elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format specifiers.

Format specifiers follow the following format:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][argsize]typechar
```

So in your case, you would do the following:

```
System.out.printf("%-23s %-14s %-12d %-5s", typeArray[i], sizeArray[i], quantityArray[i], priceArray[i]);
```

More info on format specifiers:
https://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm

Comment: Gave me bunch of errors during run, do I need to import a class?

Comment: You said typeArray and sizeArray are String arrays, quantityArray is int arrays, and priceArray is double array?

Comment: typeArray, sizeArray, and priceArray are all string arrays. quantityArray is int. priceArray is a string array becauase I am adding "$" to priceArray[i]. I can just as easily change it to a double array and print the "$" seperately if that would make it easier

Comment: Oh okay, I just assumed price was a double. I changed the type of `priceArray[i]` to be string.

Comment: Still giving me errors. Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer + others.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's been awhile since I did formatting. `f` stood for float. I changed the type to `d` which means it's an unsigned integer.

Comment: Will edit my first post to show you what errors I am getting. Do I need to import anything other than scanner class for this to work?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException` shows that you can't do specify precision on strings and ints, which makes perfect sense. I just got rid of the specifiers for all four.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102383/discussion-between-sparky-and-bankey).